# SFDX Scratchorg with Vlocity (Salesforce Industries)

Tags: vlocity

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can install Vlocity CPQ into a scratch org - I wondered if anyone has done this before and can point me in the right direction?

I cannot currently get the Vlocity package ID, as I thought I could just use this in the scratch def to install it.

Comment: Check this (http://sfdctuner.blogspot.com/2018/02/scratch-org-and-installing-cpq-package.html)